# PostgreSQL - Select the length of a numeric/decimal

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a list of prices with decimals.

Example:
0.513
0.35135
1.6583

I'm trying to select the length of the decimal digits.
Here's what I mean:
    0.513 | length=3
    0.35135 | length=5
    1.6583 | length=4

I tried converting the numbers to text, but it doesn't seem to provide correct results:
    `select price, length(cast(price as text)) from table.prices`

I also tried this conversion method: 
    "length(price::text)"

Any advice on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [scale](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-math.html) function, since postgresql 9.6 ;)

```
select scale(1.12345) as decimal_places;
 decimal_places 
----------------
              5
(1 row)
```

Comment: If your data type is float you will get `SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function scale(double precision) does not exist`. This would fix - `select (scale(cast(your_col as numeric))) as decimal_places FROM your_table`

Comment: scale(your_col::decimal) also works and is more succinct

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION decimal_places(n numeric) RETURNS int
LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE
AS $$
select coalesce(length(substring(cast($1 as text) from '\..*$')) - 1, 0);
$$;

=> select decimal_places(0.513);
┌────────────────┐
│ decimal_places │
├────────────────┤
│              3 │
└────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 2):

This code works (see [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d41d8/2077)):

```
WITH test(x) AS (VALUES (0.513), (0.35135), (1.6583))
SELECT length((x - floor(x))::text)-2
FROM test
```

There is only one gotcha - for whole integers it returns `-1`.

Comment: Can you show counter-example? It works for any values I tried

Comment: My bad, I had forgotten to delete my comment.

Comment: If you have to ignore trailing zeroes (e.g. 0.12300) you can use `SELECT length((x - floor(x::real))::text)-2`

Answer (score 0):

Write an sql or plpgsql function for this. (Or better yet, do this in your app: it probably doesn't belong in Postgres to begin with.)

The pseudocode you need is:

1. Cast the number to text.
2. Find the dot position. If none, return zero, else compute the length accordingly.

If you're dealing with stuff that have exponents, make sure you cast the values to numeric first, so as to expand e.g. `1e-12` to `0.000000000001`.

Answer (score 0):

In select can be used like this:

```
SELECT length((SELECT regexp_matches(price::text,'(\\.\\d+)')::text)), price FROM table.prices
```